# Any way to boot a OpenSuSE installation DVD ISO and install from it, without burning it to a DVD?

Tags: iso-image, opensuse, dd

Because the DVD image is too big to fit on a disk, I would like to install system using sequence of commands like this, running from an Ubuntu live CD:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://ftp.vectranet.pl/opensuse/distribution/13.1/iso/openSUSE-13.1-DVD-x86_64.iso
dd if=openSuse* of=/dev/sda4
```

where */dev/sda4* is my partition

Then I would like to be able to boot from this partition in order to launch the installer.

What should I do? When I try to boot, it says `isolinux.bin missing or corrupted`

Comment: Why? What's the problem with booting from the OpenSuSE DVD, as it's intended to be done?

Comment: dvd installation is too big for regular dvd 4.7GB

Comment: That DVD image is 4572839936 bytes, which is 4.26 GiB. Most standard- (large-) size recordable DVDs can hold 4.37 GiB [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD#Capacity). Have you actually tried writing the image to a disk, and if you did, what was the exact error message?

Comment: Actually, I am interested in [ 4.7GB DVD (also suitable for USB stick) ](http://software.opensuse.org/131/en ), therefore I'd need to get 9GB DVD for that, but anyway I would like to have knowledge how to achieve booting it without necessity of having DVD (imagine computer like dell 1018, which does not have DVD device)

Comment: (intentionally two comments in row) 
I know that the easiest solution for now is downloading [netinstall] (http://software.opensuse.org/131/en#ci_net) and downloading everything over the Internet, and that is what I've done

Answer (score 1):

Booting from CD/DVD is done using a standard called [El Torito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_%28CD-ROM_standard%29) that's different from the process used for booting from a hard drive.  The OpenSUSE installation ISO file contains El Torito boot information, but your computer probably does not support El Torito on hard drives, so you can't boot from an ISO image that's been copied to a disk partition.

You *might* be able to use the bootloader and kernel on your Ubuntu liveCD to boot the OpenSUSE installer from the disk, by specifying `root=/dev/sda4` at the CD's boot prompt.  But you'd be running OpenSUSE with Ubuntu's kernel, which may cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could install a minimal OS using [debbootstrap and chroot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebootstrapChroot). But it's not trivial. Copying the ISO image to your HDD will not work.

Comment: Hi Michael. While this answer may theoretically be quite true, we generally look for answers which go into some detail. You may want to [edit] your answer to expand on it.

Comment: @Michael Have you tried doing it? Is this, let's say, easy?

Comment: We use Ubuntu 12.04 for our Terminals and I created the base image in our server this way. And no, it's not easy, you have to keep MANY things in mind and have to do anything on the command shell. This is because I didn't go too deep. Perhaps this is way to far for your requirement.